# Ubuntu Firebird2 Classic Server config to use all CPU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, firebird, configuration-files

I am using Firebird 2.0.7 CS on my Ubuntu 16.04 Server. It is not possible to upgrade to a higher version due to the software used, which requires a lower one.
I've used the SuperServer version before, but on Linux the parameter `CpuAffinityMask` is ignored.

The SuperServer version works tragically because on Linux it uses only 1 core.
The ClassicServer version is a little better, because it assigns 1 core to the 1 user.

When I run demanding task in program, fb_inet_server use 100% of 1 core, but other 23 cores are idle. How I can assign more cores to this process?

Comment: make 24 (core's count) connections to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CpuAffinityMask` setting is only for SuperServer (and then only for Windows).

If you are using Classic Server, then Firebird can (and it will) use all cores **if there is sufficient activity**, however the Firebird processes need to coordinate their effort, which - if there is a lot of lock contention - can lead to reduced performance.

To reduce lock contention, you may want to increase the `LockHashSlots` setting.

Increasing the number of page buffers may also help, but keep in mind that with Classic Server, this setting is per process and can increase memory usage.

Contrary to what you state, Firebird does not *"assign[s] 1 core to the 1 user."*. Classic Server will create a process per connection, and the threads of these processes will be scheduled by the OS on any available core.

Comment: I set `DefaultDbCachePages` to `20480` and `LockHashSlots` to `8009`. When I run demanding task in program, fb_inet_server use 100% of 1 core, but other 23 cores are idle. How I can assign more cores to this process?

Comment: @Zafahix Each Firebird Classic Server process is largely single threaded, so it can only load a single core. If you want to do more, you need to split your work so you can use more connections, which means more cores can be used.